# Order-preserving bijection from the negative irrationals to the irrationals less than $\pi$

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, logic, set-theory, order-theory

Is there an easy to describe (using a formula or something more-or-less constructive, no zig-zag argument) an order-preserving bijection between the negative rational numbers and the rational numbers less than $\pi$?

Let $P$ be the set of all irrational numbers. Let $G$ be the set of all negative irrational numbers, let $H$ be the set of all irrational numbers greater than or equal to $\pi$, and let $Y=G\cup H$. Then $P$ and $Y$ are order-isomorphic, i.e. there is an order-preserving bijection between them.

One way to see this is to first construct an order-preserving bijection between the negative rational numbers and the rational numbers less than $\pi$, using a back-and-forth (zig-zag) argument (like the usual proof that every countably infinite dense linear order with no first or last element is order-isomorphic to the rationals). (Alternatively use that the negative rationals are a countably infinite dense linear order with no first or last element, and so are the rationals less than $\pi.$)
Once we have this bijection we could (uniquely, e.g. using Dedekind cuts) extend it to an order-preserving bijection between $(-\infty,0)$ and $(-\infty,\pi)$ (and in fact between $(-\infty,0]$ and $(-\infty,\pi]$, but I prefer to only look at the order-preserving bijection between $(-\infty,0)$ and $(-\infty,\pi)$.) Note that the latter is an order-preserving bijection that sends rationals to rationals, and  irrationals to irrationals. Taking it, together with the identity on $[\pi,\infty)$ (and restricting to the irrationals only) we get the required order-preserving bijection between $P$ and $Y$.

My **question** is whether there is an easier way to describe an order-preserving bijection between $P$ and $Y$. Or more "constructive" (in one way or another), or using some easy formula. E.g. one easy order-preserving bijection between $(-\infty,0)$ and $(-\infty,\pi)$ is translation by $\pi$, except it sends rationals to irrationals (and sends some irrationals to rationals, though it sends most irrationals to irrationals).

I feel there should be no easy way, since any easy way would send $0$ to a rational number (because that is in the nature of "easy" bijections, I would think), but $0$ must go to $\pi$ (if we extend, and get an order-preserving bijection between $(-\infty,0]$ and $(-\infty,\pi]$).
(Or $0$ may go to some other irrational, even when we don't necessarily use the identity on $[\pi,\infty)$, but at any rate $\pi$ must go to an irrational, and $0$ must "simultaneously" go to a rational and to that irrational to which $\pi$ goes, which clearly is impossible.)

So, my related **question** is: Does anybody know what I am talking about ... and could you please give me directions, references that would confirm my guess that there is no "easy" order-preserving bijection between the negative irrationals and the irrationals strictly less than $\pi$? (Equivalently, that there is no "easy" order-preserving bijection between the negative rationals and the rationals less than $\pi$.) (Or, perhaps there is such an order-preserving bijection that might qualify as "easy?")

The answer would need to include a mathematically precise definition of "easy" (with the risk that I would not be able to understand it, but that is another matter, just try your best to come up with what you believe is an appropriate answer). What area of mathematics is involved (what books do I need to read)?

Edit. The answer posted by Brian M. Scott shows we could get a piecewise linear order-preserving bijection (which one might argue is as good as it gets). It is clear (or easy to see) that we could not remove "piecewise." I was asking for an "easy" bijection, and now I am starting to think that I was conflating "easy" with "nice," though without specific definitions one can interpret my question any way that might be reasonable. So here is a version of the problem where at least the term "nice" is given some possible interpretations. I guess I am hoping for a negative answer (for whatever reason) so I am putting some extra conditions on the bijection which may turn out to be impossible.

**Is there** an order-preserving bijection between $(-\infty,0)$ and $(-\infty,\pi)$ that sends rationals to rationals, sends irrationals to irrationals, and such that: (a) it is differentiable, or (b) it is $C^{\infty}$, or (c) it is analytic, or (d) it is something even nicer, e.g. given by an algebraic expression, or (somehow) given using the solutions (roots) of a polynomial? Is there any irrational number $p$ and order-preserving bijection between $(-\infty,0)$ and $(-\infty,p)$ that sends rationals to rationals, sends irrationals to irrationals, and such that any of (a) through (d) above might hold? I am thinking that perhaps (a) or (b) could have positive answer, while there is no way that (c) or (d) have positive answers, but I do not know, and I don't even know what area of math might turn out to be relevant. Any ideas or references (if something like this was already considered) would be appreciated. I don't really have any applications but this question seems interesting to me. (My guess is that these variations may just make the question difficult to handle.)

Given any rationals $p<q$ and $r<s$ there is a linear (or perhaps one should say affine) map $y=mx+b$ that sends $[p,q]$ to $[r,s]$ (as given in the answer by Brian M. Scott, $x\mapsto r+\frac{s-r}{q-p}(x-p),$ where $m=\frac{s-r}{q-p}$ and $b=r-\frac{s-r}{q-p}p$, both $m$ and $b$ rational). I just seem to be unable to take it that you couldn't do the same if the endpoints are irrational.
Say $[\frac{-\pi}2,\frac{-\pi}3]$ and $[\pi-\frac{\pi}2,\pi-\frac{\pi}3]$ are clearly two intervals of the same length and with all endpoints involved being irrational. One is tempted to expect that in this case one could translate one interval to the other, sending rationals to rationals and irrationals to irrationals, but this is clearly not the case as the translation $x\mapsto \pi+x$ send rationals to irrationals. (All this is soo irrational... :)
I guess all this just illustrates that the irrationals are much "thicker" than the rationals, and the set of translations that sends rationals to rationals is "thin" in the set of all possible translations. (The translation $x\mapsto q+x$ "works" only if $q$ is rational.) I am tempted to visualize this using the integers instead: The intervals $(n,n+1)$ in between the integers (for integer $n$) are "thick" so the only translations $x\mapsto t+x$ that send integers to integers are when $t$ is an integer. So I may want to come up with a question about "nice" order-preserving functions from the integers *into* the integers (aiming at making the existence of such functions to be "difficult",: I just don't know how to come up with a condition in this case that is analogous to asking that $(-\infty,0)$ maps onto $(-\infty,\pi)$ (when we consider rationals and irrationals as in the original version of my question).
(End of edit.)

Regarding the extension of an order-preserving bijection from the rationals to the reals (if someone needs to see the details), see [Extension of order-preserving bijection from rationals to reals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046686/extension-of-order-preserving-bijection-from-rationals-to-reals)

A closely-related question seems to be:
[Order preserving bijection from ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}$ to $\mathbb Q$,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542860/order-preserving-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q)
where one asks for "wondering if something simpler could be given, more analytic."
There are two answers there, the accepted one starts with "surreal numbers up to generation $\omega$," which is not something familiar to me. I would need to take a more careful look at those answers, but I feel that my version of this question is "different" because $\pi$ is an endpoint (and the irrationals rather than rationals are involved), and there are no endpoints in ${\mathbb Q}\times{\mathbb Q}.$

Regarding how I came up with this, I don't remember anymore, but I was thinking of subsets of the reals that are not $F_\sigma$ but are reverse order-isomorphic to themselves (the set $P$ being one example with $p\mapsto-p$), and at some point realized that there seemed to be no "easy" order-isomorphism between certain sets, and felt curious to find out more about this, as asked above.

(I am puzzled there is no tag "linear-orders." There is "order-theory," but that is too general, seems mostly about partial orders(?), and there is "well-orders," but this is too narrow.)

Comment: This is not an answer, but I find the question quite interesting. How come we cannot take the map $x \mapsto -1/(x-\pi)$? Edit: Oops, I did something backwards.

Comment: @marcelgoh because I want my map to send rationals to rationals (and irrationals to irrationals, depending on which version of the problem you read), but if $x$ is rational then $-1/(x-\pi)$ is irrational. (That is, maynly because of that, in addition to your correction that you did something "backwards" ... I don't see which intervals it is supposed to send to which.)

Comment: I mean, the "zig-zag argument" is actually perfectly constructive in this case; it's even computable.

Comment: @EricWofsey you are likely right, except I am not comfortable (that is I am not familiar) with exact definitions of "constructive" and "computable", so I am unable to appreciate your comment ... and for that matter my question. (I guess I may be thinking naively of a bijection which is given by some "formula", some simple algebraic expression, which might indeed be too much to ask for, but which, to my "intuition" is "constructive".)

Comment: You can write a computer program that, when you input a rational number less than 0 (written as a fraction of integers), outputs a rational number less than $\pi$, such that the function it gives is an order-preserving bijection (and is in fact the bijection given by a certain implementation of the "zig-zag argument").

Comment: @EricWofsey I realize my question is unclear, as "easy" is not defined (and should be defined in the answer). I glanced through the answer that Brian M. Scott posted, and I imagine the computer program must first generate a (preferably increasing) sequence of rationals converging to $\pi$. I have to agree that this sounds "easy enough", though perhaps I was hoping for something even easier (or show it does not exist ... subject to figuring what I mean by easy). At any rate, what I got from the comments and the answer posted so far does help.

Comment: Please correct either your title or your first sentence. Are you talking about rational or irrational numbers?

Comment: @TonyK My original question was about the irrationals, and I had a long intro before asking a question. Then I thought that my preliminary explanations were too long, and moved my question to the top, but put the version with rationals. They are equivalent since each of the rationals and irrationals are dense, so if you get one bijection e.g. for the rationals you could extend it to all negative reals, and then restrict to irrationals (or vice versa).

Comment: They are most definitey not equivalent, at least not until you tell us exactly what you mean by _negative_. Why don't you decide what you mean, and correct your question accordingly? It just looks stupid as it is.

Comment: @Tony Negative means less than $0$. Let $Q$ be the set of all rational numbers. If you find an order-preserving bijection from $Q\cap(-\infty,0)$ to $Q\cap(-\infty,\pi)$ then you could uniquely extend it to an order-preserving bijection from $(-\infty,0)$ to $(-\infty,\pi)$, after which you could restrict the latter to obtain an order-preserving bijection from $P\cap(-\infty,0)$ to $P\cap(-\infty,\pi)$. Similarly if you start with an order-preserving bijection from $P\cap(-\infty,0)$ to $P\cap(-\infty,\pi)$ then get one from $Q\cap(-\infty,0)$ to $Q\cap(-\infty,\pi)$,to explain the equivalence

Comment: Theorem (Cantor). If $(A,<_A)$ and $(A',<_{A'})$ are countably infinite linear orders, each without endpoints and each order-dense in itself then they are order-isomorphic. (...An order $<$ is order-dense in itself when $a<b\implies \exists c\,(a<c<b)$...). This pre-dates modern Model Theory, so I suspect that Cantor did not use a back-&-forth argument. There is an entirely elementary proof.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you,I thought Cantor invented the back-and-forth argument, but I would have to look for a reference to confirm. Do you have a specific "entirely elementary proof" in mind, any details? Wikipedia says there is no evidence it was Cantor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method#History I wonder what was Cantor's proof (Wikipedia says Cantor(1895) but does not provide a specific reference). And,would the elementary proof produce an order-preserving bijection from the negative rationals to rationals $<\pi$ (i.e. would this extra condition have any bearing at all)?

Comment: Let $A=\{a_n: n\in \Bbb N_0\}$ and $A'=\{a'_n: n\in \Bbb N_0\}.$ Let $f(a_0)=a'_0.$ Let $P(0)=Q(0)=0$. For brevity, for $n\in \Bbb N$ let $R(n)=\{a_{P(j)}:j\le n\}$ and $S(n)=\{f(x):x\in R(n)\}.$  If $f:R(n)\to S(n)$ preserves order then let $P(n+1)$ be the least $m$ such that $a_m\not\in R(n)$ and let $Q(n+1)$ be the least $m'$ such that if $f(a_{P(n+1)})=a'_{m'}$ then $f: R(n+1)\to S(n+1)$ preserves order.  Now show by induction on $k$ that every $a_k\in \cup_n R(n)$ and every $a'_k\in \cup_n S(n).$

Comment: @D According to https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/nedlagte-emner/INF5170/v14/undervisningsmateriale/countable-densely-ordered-sets.pdf (Any two countable densely ordered sets without endpoints are isomorphic a formal proof with KIV, Martin Giese Arno Schonegge), "Georg Cantor in [1] gave the first "informal" proof for the fact
that any two countable densely ordered sets without endpoints are isomorphic." G. Cantor, Gesammelte Abhandlungen ch.9,p.303 Springer 1932. Also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101996/cantor-theorem-on-orders addresses this question (answer unclear)

Comment: Mirko, just for your information, negative can mean $<0$ or $\le 0$. You should always specify which one you mean when it makes a difference.

Comment: @TonyK thank you, but $0$ is not negative. I do not have to specify that $0$ is not negative. $0$ is the only number that is neither positive nor negative. If you believe that negative could mean $\le0$ then you should correct your understanding.

Comment: A question of definition. But please, Mirko, let us know whether you mean rational or irrarional. Then I can edit your question for you if you don't want to do it yourself.

Comment: @TonyK Please do NOT edit my question. It has been clarified both in the question and in the comments that it doesn't matter whether you consider the version with "rational" or with "irrational". I am happy with my question as is. Re "a question of definition" I only know of one definition of negative. I do not know what other possible definitions you might want to adopt, but $\le0$ means less that of equal to $0$, and negative means $<0$.

Comment: In my most recent comment above, in the 2nd-last line it should say "such that if $Q(n+1)=a'_{m'}$ & if $f(a_{P(n+1)})=a'_{m'}$ then $f:R(n+1)\to S(n+1)$ preserves order."

Comment: @D In his 1895/97 papers "Beiträge zur Begründung der transfiniten Mengenlehre", Cantor proved that any two countable dense orders without endpoints are isomorphic, according to this article by Charles Silver. The above comes from a comment by user Goldstern, to answer https://mathoverflow.net/q/101999 but link to Silver's article doesn't work. You might want to elevate your comments to an answer. It seems very close in spirit to the back-and-forth argument,except the "back" step is missing and the "forward" improved,and using least elements, rather than any. I wonder if this is Cantor's proof

Comment: @Mirko . I haven't researched the history of this theorem of Cantor. I had it as an assigned problem, without knowing about "back & forth". The solution in my previous comment is a streamlined version of what I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not precisely easy, but here is a piecewise linear order-preserving bijection.

First, suppose that $p,q,r,s\in\Bbb Q$, $p<q$, and $r<s$. Let

$$h_{p,q,r,s}:(p,q)\to(r,s)\setminus\Bbb Q:x\mapsto r+\frac{s-r}{q-p}(x-p)\,$$

$h_{p,q,r,s}$ is an order-preserving bijection that takes rationals to rationals and irrationals to irrationals, so its restriction to $(p,q)\setminus\Bbb Q$ is a bijection to $(r,s)\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Now let $a_n=-2^{-n}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, and let $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence in $\Bbb Q$ converging to $\pi$ such that $b_0=-1=a_0$. Let $f_0$ be the identity map on $(\leftarrow,-1)\setminus\Bbb Q$, and for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $f_n=h_{a_{n-1},a_n,b_{n-1},b_n}$. Then

$$f=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}f_n:(\leftarrow,0)\setminus\Bbb Q\to(\leftarrow,\pi)\setminus\Bbb Q$$

is an order-preserving bijection.